# Is it possible to connect your background script to mongoDB server? If Yes, How?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a google chrome extension. I have a background script from which I want to send and retrieve some data from MongoDB database. How do I do that? I'm new in chrome extension development.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES. It's possible. But, It's not a good idea to expose a database to the public internet at all. Implement a REST like method in your backend code and authorize calls to it using some web standard auth scheme, such as OAuth or HTTP Basic auth. Hitting the DB directly is way too dangerous. You can receive/send data from DB accordingly. Saying That if you still want to go ahead here's [a link](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) to help you with that For full REST capabilities, consider using an external REST Interface such as [Sleepy.Mongoose](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/).

Comment: Can i use node js as an alternative?

Comment: @SanketPandilwar Yes indeed.. It's widely used in MEAN stack projects..